Why does the denominator of the Pad\'e Approximation to Exponential function approximate $e^{-x/2}$?
In the Paper "Nineteen Dubious Ways to Compute the Exponential of a Matrix, Twenty-Five Years Later", there is a statement that "For large $q$, $D_{qq}(A)$ approaches the series for $e^{-A/2}$ whereas $N_{qq}(A)$ tends to the series for $e^{A/2}$" in the part of "Method 2. Pad'e Approximation". Here,
$$N_{pq}(A) = \sum_{j=0}^p \frac{(p+q-j)!p!}{(p+q)!j!(p-j)!}A^j,$$
$$D_{pq}(A) = \sum_{j=0}^q \frac{(p+q-j)!q!}{(p+q)!j!(q-j)!}(-A)^j.$$
Intuitively, I can understand it in the following way. In the case $p = q$, we use $d_j$ to denote the coefficients of the two polynomials, i.e.
$$d_j = \frac{(2q-j)!q!}{(2q)!j!(q-j)!}.$$
Then, we have $d_0 = 1$ and
$$\frac{d_{j+1}}{d_j} = \frac{q-j}{(j+1)(2q-j)}.$$
Thus, when $q$ is large and $j$ is smaller than $q$ significantly, we may have
$$\frac{d_{j+1}}{d_j}\approx \frac{1}{j+1}\cdot \frac12,$$
which further implies that
$$d_{j} \approx \frac{1}{2^j j!}. $$
For much larger $j$, the quantity $d_j$ can be quite small, and the corresponding terms in the polynomial can be negligible. Finally, we may have
$$D_{qq}(A) \approx \sum_{j=0}^{m} d_j (-A)^j\approx \sum_{j=0}^{m} \frac{1}{j!} \left(-\frac{A}{2}\right)^j \approx e^{-A/2},$$
where $m$ is positive integer smaller than $q$.
I wonder if there is any theoretical result about this statement, which can give a rigorous error bound between $D_{qq}(A)$ and $e^{-A/2}$.

Consider $e^x=\frac{e^{x/2}}{e^{-x/2}}$
